# How do I manipulate single bits of an array

Tags: c

So I defined a struct with a array of unsigned chars in a header.

```
#ifndef BITSTREAM_H
#define BITSTREAM_H

typedef struct {
int lengthofarray;
int position;
unsigned char* arrayofunsignedchar;
}Bitstream;

#endif // INTARRAY_H
```

I created the struct including the array with the length of 8 in the int main function. And set all bits of the field to 0 within the create function. But the bitmanipulation function is where I am struggling.

```
int main(void)
{
Bitstream * bs = malloc(sizeof(Bitstream));
create(bs, &length);
destroy(bs);
bs = malloc(sizeof(Bitstream));
create(bs, &length);      
bitmanipulation(bs, 4, 4);
bitmanipulation(bs, 9, 27);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now I want to code the function bitmanipulation to set a given number of bits of this array to a given value. I know I have to do it with bitwise and & or bitwise OR | . But I am not sure, for example, how to adress only the last 3 bits of my first array element. I guess I would have to compare it bitwise to an unsigned int which first 5 bits are 0 but then I dont know how to design it inside the function to work for every given number of bits and value. It would be awesome if someone could give me an example how to manipulate just a part of the bits of an array element.

```
void bitmanipulation(Bitstream * bs, int numberofbits, int valueofbits){
//printf("%d position\n", (*bs).position);
//here should be the code to change the "numberofbits" bits before 
to be represent the valueofbits.
if((*bs).position == 0){
(*bs).position = (numberofbits-1);
}else {
(*bs).position = (*bs).position + numberofbits;
}
printf("%d position\n", (*bs).position);
printf("%d value of the element\n", (*bs).arrayofunsignedchar[0]);

}

bitmanipulation(bs, 4, 4);
// this should only manipulate the first 4 bits in the array 
arrayofunsignedchar and only set bit 2 to be 1. So Bit 0;1;3 would still
be 0 and they would be 0 from now on. And it updates the position to be 3;


bitmanipulation(bs, 9, 27);
//this now would have to manipulate bit 4 to bit 12; So It 
would set bit 4, bit 5, bit 7, bit 8; and bit 6;9;10;11;12 
would be 0 from now on. And it updates the position to be 12;
```

So it would treat the arrayofunsigned char as a bitfield. And after the first functioncall of bitmanipulation the first 4 bits would represend the value 4. And then the second f1unction call would manipulate the next 9 bits in the bitfield. And the would represent the value 27. And so on for example 
bitmanipulation(bs, 2,0) would just do nothing since bit 13 and 14 are 0 already. If I call bitmanipulation(bs, 2,2) now it would change bit 16 to be 1 so these 2 bits "15" and "16" together would represent the number 1.

After I call bitmanipulation the last time I would print the arrayofunsignedchar represented by a line of unsigned ints. In this example it would be

```
arrayofunsignedchar[0] = 180 (00101101)
arrayofunsignedchar[1] = 1 (10000000)
arrayofunsignedchar[2] = 1 (10000000)
```

so the print out would be 180;1;1;0;0;0;0;0   .

Comment: Please give examples of sample input, sample operation to do on it and the desired output; for several different inputs and operations.

Answer (score 0):

considering that 
4 is 100 in binary and that 9 is 1001 in binary

```
 void bitmanipulation(Bitstream * bs, const int numberofbits, const int valueofbits) {
     int write=valueofbits;
     for(int i=0;i<numberofbits;++i) {
         if(write%2==1) { 
             // put 1 bit at position+i in bs->arrayofunsignedchar
         }else{
             // put 0 bit at position+i in bs->arrayofunsignedchar
         }
         write /= 2;
     }
     ...
 }
```

Putting `1` at position `n` in an array of `unsigned char` would require you to calculate at which `unsigned char` you want to write to ( assuming `unsigned char` is 8 bit long)

```
void writeBit(unsigned char* output,const int position,const int value) {
    int charIndex=position/8;
    int bitInCharIndex=position%8;

    unsigned char input= 1;
    input <<= bitInCharIndex;

    if(value==1) {
        output[charIndex] |= input;
        return;
    }
    // else 0
    input = ~input;
    output[charIndex] &= input;
}
```

be mindful of not exceeding the array length.

Comment: Thank you Im gonna try it tomorrow but it looks like its pretty much what I was looking for. I will try it tomorrow its pretty late already.

Comment: It worked fine thank you. I never would have thought of the modulo loop myself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to dvhh I could finish it.

```
void bitmanipulation(Bitstream * bs, const int numberofbits, const int valueofbits) {
    int k = valueofbits;
    if ((*bs).position == 0) {
    printf("%d position\n", (*bs).position);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <numberofbits; i++){
    if ((*bs).position > ((8*(*bs).lengthofarray)-1)){
    return;
    }
    if (k%2==1) {
    int charIndex = (*bs).position/8;
    int bitInCharIndex = (*bs).position%8;
    unsigned int input = 1;
    input <<= bitInCharIndex;
    (*bs).arrayofunsignedchar[charIndex] |= input;
    }
    k = k/2;
    (*bs).position = (*bs).position + 1;
    printf("%d position\n", (*bs).position);
    } 
    }

    void printthearray(Bitstream * bs){
    for (int i = 0; i < (*bs).lengthofarray; i++){
    unsigned char t = (*bs).arrayofunsignedchar[i];
    printf("%u ist das %dte Element des Arrays als Ganzzahl\n", t, i);
    }
    }

    int main(void)
    {
    Bitstream * bs = malloc(sizeof(Bitstream));
    create(bs, 10);
    destroy(bs);
    bs = malloc(sizeof(Bitstream));
    create(bs, 10);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 4, 4);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 9, 27);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 6, 27);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 4, 4);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 9, 27);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 6, 27);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 4, 4);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 9, 27);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 6, 27);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 4, 4);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 9, 27);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 6, 27);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 4, 4);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 9, 27);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 6, 27);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 4, 4);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 9, 27);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 6, 27);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 6, 27);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 4, 4);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 9, 27);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 6, 27);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 4, 4);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 9, 27);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 6, 27);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 4, 4);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 9, 27);
    bitmanipulation(bs, 6, 27);
    printthearray(bs);
    destroy(bs);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

    }
```

So the program would print

```
180 ist das 0te Element des Arrays als Ganzzahl 
// translated into English: 180 is the 0 element of the array 
// printed as an unsigned int.
97 ist das 1te Element des Arrays als Ganzzahl
163 ist das 2te Element des Arrays als Ganzzahl
13 ist das 3te Element des Arrays als Ganzzahl
27 ist das 4te Element des Arrays als Ganzzahl
109 ist das 5te Element des Arrays als Ganzzahl
216 ist das 6te Element des Arrays als Ganzzahl
104 ist das 7te Element des Arrays als Ganzzahl
195 ist das 8te Element des Arrays als Ganzzahl
70 ist das 9te Element des Arrays als Ganzzahl
```